# Oracle Database 10G Query to be solved

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
create table customer
    (cust_id    integer     not null,
    cust_name   char(20)    not null ,
    cust_address    varchar2(200)   ,
    emp_id      integer     not null,
        constraint pk_customer primary key(cust_id)
    );

create table account
    (account_number integer     not null,
    account_balance number(8,2) not null,
    constraint pk_acount primary key(account_number)
    );
create table has
    (cust_id    integer     not null,
        account_number  integer     not null,
        constraint pk_has primary key(cust_id, account_number)
        );
alter table has
add constraint fk_account_has foreign key(account_number) 
references account(account_number);

alter table has 
add constraint fk_customer_has foreign key(cust_id) 
references customer(cust_id);

alter table customer 
add constraint fk_employee_customer foreign key(emp_id) 
references employee(emp_id);
```

Q1 Show all the information about the customers with account number 101 and account number 102

Q2 Show the account numbers and the customer IDs for all customers with account balance higher than 500.

Q3 Show all the information about the customers with account balances that differ from 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```
select c.cust_id, c.cust_address, c.cust_address
from customer c join has h on h.cust_id = c.cust_id
where h.account_number in (101, 102);
```

I suggest you **STOP** reading now and - looking at the first example - try to write the next 2 queries yourself.

```
select c.cust_id, h.account_Number
from customer c join has h on h.cust_id = c.cust_id
join account a on a.account_number = h.account_number
where a.account_balance > 500;

select c.cust_id, c.cust_address, c.cust_address
from customer c join has h on h.cust_id = c.cust_id
join account a on a.account_number = h.account_number
where a.account_balance <> 500;
```

Comment: select*
from customer c,has h
where c.cust_id=h.cust_id and account_number in(101,102);

Is this method good ?

Comment: It will work, no doubt, but it is suggested to use explicit JOIN instead of the *oldfashioned* one, where all tables you use are separated by comma in the FROM clause. JOIN has its advantages, especially when outer joining the same table to two (or more) other tables, which is impossible using the old Oracle `(+)` outer join operator.

Comment: Much Thanks for the clarifications Littlefoot